# I was trying to find field due uniformly charged sheet at a distance h from centre of the square sheet

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, electromagnetism

I assumed the square(side a) sheet to be made up of wires.$$dE=Kdq/r^2$$
The field due to a wire is :  [Reference](https://byjus.com/question-answer/electric-field-strength-due-to-a-uniformly-charge-rod-1/)
$$\frac{K\lambda}{d}\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}\right]^{(a/2)}_{(-a/2)}=\frac{K\lambda}{d}\left[\frac{2a}{\sqrt{4d^2+a^2}}\right]$$ where $d$ is the distance between the centre of rod/wire and the point and $\lambda$ is charge density

Now for finding the field due to the square plate, I used this integral:
$$\int{\left( \cfrac{2K\sigma ah}{(h^2+y^2)\sqrt{4(h^2+y^2)+a^2}}\right) dy}$$
$h$ is the height of the point above centre of plate $\sigma$ is surface charge density. And since horizontal components cancel out, $\sin\theta=h/d$ has been multiplied.

Assuming $\tan\theta=y/h$, the integral gives:
$$\int{\left( \cfrac{2K\sigma a}{h\sqrt{4h^2\sec^6\theta+a^2\sec^4\theta}}\right) d\tan\theta}$$
$$=\int{\left( \cfrac{2K\sigma a}{h\sqrt{4h^2\sec^2\theta+a^2}}\right) d\theta}$$

**How do I proceed further?
Are there any alternatives to evaluate that integral?**

PS: Here are two images for visualization but the variables are I used are different so bear with that.
[image: The problem 'd' here is 'h' for me]
[image: For a wire]

Comment: Physics stack exchange: https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The answer might be $$4K\sigma \tan^{-1}\left( \cfrac{a^2}{4h\sqrt{a^2/2+h^2}}\right)$$ but I can't reach there so why would it matter?

Comment: @AlexByard The reason I am asking here is because physicsSE doesn't really help a lot in solving the integral. Do you suggest I should edit it to the concerned integral only? Instead of all that physics  I have written before

Comment: Honestly, I would edit it to just contain some motivation, but I'll solve it for you now so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the shortest solution, but here we go. We want to compute
$$
\int\frac{2K\sigma ah}{(h^2+y^2)\sqrt{4(h^2+y^2)+a^2}}dy.
$$
Rearranging, this is the same as
$$
2K\sigma ah\int\frac{1}{(h^2+y^2)\sqrt{4y^2+4h^2+a^2}}dy.
$$
We make the substitution $y=\frac{\sqrt{4h^2+a^2}}{2}\tan(\theta)$ with $dy=\frac{\sqrt{4h^2+a^2}}{2}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$.
Our integral becomes
$$
2K\sigma ah\frac{\sqrt{4h^2+a^2}}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{(h^2+\frac{4h^2+a^2}{4}\tan^2(\theta))\sqrt{4h^2+a^2}\sec(\theta)}d\theta,
$$
or
$$
K\sigma ah\int\frac{\sec(\theta)}{h^2+\frac{4h^2+a^2}{4}\tan^2(\theta)}d\theta.
$$
This is the same as
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{\sec(\theta)}{4h^2+(4h^2+a^2)\tan^2(\theta)}d\theta.
$$
Now $\sec(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$, so this integral is the same as
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{1}{4h^2\cos(\theta)+(4h^2+a^2)\cos(\theta)\tan^2(\theta)}d\theta.
$$
Since $\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$, this is the same as
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{1}{4h^2\cos(\theta)+(4h^2+a^2)\sin(\theta)\tan(\theta)}d\theta,
$$
or
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{4h^2\cos^2(\theta)+(4h^2+a^2)\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta.
$$
Distributing, this yields
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{4h^2\cos^2(\theta)+4h^2\sin^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta,
$$
and a trig identity gives us
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{4h^2+a^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta.
$$
Let $u=\sin(\theta)$, so that $du=\cos(\theta)d\theta$. With this substitution, our integral becomes
$$
4K\sigma ah\int\frac{1}{4h^2+a^2u^2}du.
$$
A standard trig substitution should solve this integral. I think the solution is
$$
4K\sigma ah\frac{1}{2ha}\arctan\left(\frac{au}{2h}\right)+C=2K\sigma\arctan\left(\frac{au}{2h}\right)+C.
$$
Now we have to undo our substitutions. We get first that the integral is equal to
$$
2K\sigma\arctan\left(\frac{a\sin(\theta)}{2h}\right)+C.
$$
You can continue substituting in the rest for $\theta$, as I don't really want to work through the computations to simplify this.